# SingleChildScrollView isn't working when putting it above Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this structure in my app as shown in the attached photo and I want to Wrap the third Column with a SingleChildScrollView but it's not working and When I put it above the first Column it works!

How do I solve this problem?!

[please review this photo to better understand my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBgbh.png)

Comment: In the future, photos should not be used for sharing code. Pasting it into the question would be more helpful.

Comment: I can not reproduce this problem with the way your code is posted right now

Comment: why wcyankees424 ?

Comment: Please do add your code here , instead of giving image of code It will help experts to resolve your question as soon as possible and also you don't need to add whole class code , just snippets of it which is giving problem (meana you can add same code shown in image here) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on facebook and the answer was to wrap the second Column with a SingleChildScrollView and then wrap it with a Container and then Wrap this container with an Expanded Widget and it worked just fine!

Expanded->Container->SingleChildScrollView-> 2nd Column